# Almost a month, transaction still not confirmed... help?

Tags: transaction-fees

I sent a transaction of 0.12 BTC with a fee of 11 sat/b. I expected the transaction to take a while to send, like a week, but it's already been almost a month. Is there something I can do to boost the transaction? A month ago I also sent a transaction of 0.03 BTC with a 15 sat/b fee and it took 4 hours to confirm. I didn't expected the 11 sat/b fee to take so much longer...

Comment: RBF (Replace-By-Fee) will solve your problem. What wallet do you use?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the RBF. I'm using a Copay wallet.

Comment: It seems this is an [open issue](https://github.com/bitpay/copay/issues/5935) on their GitHub regarding RBF support.

Comment: If you export your private key from [Copay](https://github.com/bitpay/copay/wiki/COPAY---FAQ) to Electrum, you may be able to double-spend the transaction.

Answer (score -1):

You can enable in Copay/BitPay Wallet the option for use unconfirmed spents... So you can re-send it with a fee greater than the last you used